# Variable storage limit in NodeJS/ExpressJS server with multiple users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, memory-management, performance-testing

I want to store some temporary data (objects and arrays) in variables inside the node server code.
These variables are stored in the client variable of a socket and cleaned on connection loss with the client.
My question is, what's the limit to the memory usage whith this method when there are hundreds or thousands of users connected to the server? Is it something to worry about? Is this method better than fetching the data multiple times a minute from a Mongo database for each user?
I'm really curious about this, regarding system performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends upon how large the data is.   Just multiple the estimated size of your data times the number of simultaneous connected users and then double it (for JS storage overhead) and see how big that is.  This is not meant to be an exact calculation, but to give you a ballpark figure to examine.

For example, if you had 5k of data times 10,000 users the above equation would be:

```
5120 x 10,000 x 2 = 102,400,000 bytes or 98MB
```

In the normal scheme of things, you'd have a server with gigabytes of memory available.

> Is it something to worry about?

So, plug in your own data size and compare to the typical free memory you have in your server.  In most cases this example would be just fine as 100MB is no big deal unless you're running in some low memory configuration.

> Is this method better than fetching the data multiple times a minute from a Mongo database for each user?

If you have the appropriate memory and you don't have update issues with caching the data like this, it will be faster to cache the data in memory like this than constantly querying Mongo for it.